# Does LiveDataScope block of code runs only one time after emit()?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

As said in title, does LiveDataScope block of code runs only one time after emit()?
Is it possible to make my LiveDataScope block of code run more than one time, because i need to make request to server, and if it fails i would like to call same code to try again.

Sample of code:

```
    fun refreshLiveDataResource() = liveData(Dispatchers.Main){
        val retriveRoutes = remoteDataSourceKt.getRoutes()
        if(retriveRoutes.data != null){
            routeList = retriveRoutes.data
        }
        emit(retriveRoutes)
      }
```

when i call this function, after emit() if i call function again, never gets inside.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `LiveData` once and update its value whenever you need it instead of creating a new one everytime you want to retry. I would use a `Flow` instead, to update the `LiveData`, with a `retry` operator in case there is some error, like this:

```
val routesLiveData =
    remoteDataSourceKt.getRoutes()
        .onEach { retriveRoutes ->
            if(retriveRoutes.data != null){
                routeList = retriveRoutes.data
            }
        }
        .retry(3) { e -> // retries up to 3 times; no argument means retrying forever
            (e is IOException) // retry on any IOException but also introduce delay if retrying
                .also {
                    if (it)
                        delay(1000)
                }
        }
        .asLiveData()
```

You'll have to:

1. Make `getRoutes()` method return a `Flow`.
2. Make sure the `Flow` works on `Dispatchers.IO`.
3. Observe `myLiveData` from your UI.